# Deciding whether an arbitrary context-free grammar generates a deterministic push-down automata?

Tags: automata-theory, context-free, grammars, decidability

I know that it's undecidable whether an arbitrary context-free grammar is *ambiguous*, but is it decidable whether that grammar is *deterministic*? I can't find the answer to this question anywhere on the internet.

Clarification: I don't care about deciding if the *language* is deterministic, just whether a specific *grammar* is deterministic.

Comment: Yes it is decidable, a sketch of the proof can be found in this lecture: [Deterministic Context-Free Languages](http://basics.sjtu.edu.cn/~chen/teaching/TOC/sip5.pdf); they start establishing the equivalence between DCFGs and endmarked languages; then costruct a special DFA DK to identify "handles" and determine whether
the grammar is deterministic by examining DK's accept states.